# MySQL: Multiple Joins to Same Table & then to Another Table in Same Row

Tags: mysql

I am working in LAMP environment.

In MySQL I have **3 tables** & I want to create the **desired report** as mentioned in below attached image.

[image]

How I can achieve this.

Comment: In the future, please include what queries/work you had attempted, with your question.

Comment: My current approach was: Join Table-1 & Table-2. Then Query Table-3. Then using PHP loop join results of both queries to get the desired report. Now if we compare a pure MySQL solution as suggested by @Ethilium with the MySQL+PHP approach, I think pure MySQL solution will be more efficient.What do you think?

Comment: For this solution, the MySQL only option is ideal. You don't want to pass extra data to PHP other than what you need. Not only is that additional overhead for your site backend, but it creates a second point of failure for the query instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of table ProductMaster allowing non-ID integers in its FK_ProductTag_# fields, a special join is needed for each Attribute (assuming each FK_ProductTag_# can have a "0" value. Here is the requested query:

```
select a.ProductName as 'Product Name', 
a.Attr1 as 'Atrribute-1', 
b.Attr2 as 'Attribute-2', 
c.Attr3 as 'Atrribute-3' from
  (select m.ProductName as 'ProductName',
  concat_ws(': ', tagtype.Description, tag1.Description) as 'Attr1'
  from ProductMaster m
  left join ProductTag tag1 on m.FK_ProductTag_1 = tag1.ID
  left join ProductTagType tagtype on tag1.FK_ProductTagType = tagtype.ID) as a
join
  (select m.ProductName as 'ProductName',
  concat_ws(': ', tagtype.Description, tag2.Description) as 'Attr2'
  from ProductMaster m
  left join ProductTag tag2 on m.FK_ProductTag_2 = tag2.ID
  left join ProductTagType tagtype on tag2.FK_ProductTagType = tagtype.ID) as b
on a.ProductName = b.ProductName
join
  (select m.ProductName as 'ProductName',
  concat_ws(': ', tagtype.Description, tag3.Description) as 'Attr3'
  from ProductMaster m
  left join ProductTag tag3 on m.FK_ProductTag_3 = tag3.ID
  left join ProductTagType tagtype on tag3.FK_ProductTagType = tagtype.ID) as c
on a.ProductName = c.ProductName
order by a.ProductName asc
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25d6a4/14) for a demo.

SQLFiddle was acting up during testing, so copy the above query and the below table schema into [SQLTest](http://sqltest.net/#) for a demo:

```
create table ProductTagType (ID int not null auto_increment, Description varchar(20), primary key (ID));
create table ProductTag (ID int not null auto_increment, Description varchar(20), FK_ProductTagType int(1), primary key (ID));
create table ProductMaster (ID int not null auto_increment, ProductName varchar(20), FK_ProductTag_1 int(1), FK_ProductTag_2 int(1), FK_ProductTag_3 int(1), primary key (ID));
insert into ProductTagType (Description)
values ('Imported'), ('Local'), ('HomeMade');
insert into ProductTag (Description, FK_ProductTagType)
values ('Wood', 2), ('Plastic', 2), ('Steel', 1), ('Aluminum', 3);
insert into ProductMaster (ProductName, FK_ProductTag_1, FK_ProductTag_2, FK_ProductTag_3)
values ('Chair', 1, 2, 3), ('Table', 0, 3, 4);
```